# add AD account with custom attribute using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to add an account using powershell along with a cutom attribute. Schema extension is done and from attribute editor i can see that value of custom attribute "test" is not set.

```
$pw = "jakdakjdJAKJKA123";
$spw = ConvertTo-SecureString $pw -AsPlainText -force;
$accountname = "mytest";
$des = "Description";
$otherAttributes = @{'test' = "testval"};
New-AdUser -UserPrincipalName "$accountname@testdomain.local" -path "OU=Services,OU=Users,OU=OrgA,DC=testdomain,DC=local" -Name "$accountname" -SamAccountName "$accountname" -GivenName "$accountname" -Description $des -CannotChangePassword $true -DisplayName "$accountname" -PasswordNeverExpires $true -AccountPassword $spw -Enabled $true -otherAttributes $otherAttributes
```

when i run above code i get an error.

```
New-AdUser : The parameter is incorrect
At line:6 char:1
+ New-AdUser -UserPrincipalName "$accountname@testdomain.local" -path "OU=S ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CN=mytest...testdomain,DC=local:String) [New-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:87,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

if i remove "-otherAttributes $otherAttributes", account will be added successfully.

Question is how can i add account with custom attribute?

Comment: What is the syntax of the custom attribute? Can you share its schema perhaps (or at least its values for `lDAPDisplayName`, `oMSyntax`, `attributeSyntax`, and `isSingleValued` in the schema)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - i can not but your question helped me to figure out the problem. It was an type Integer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take the email out of the UserPrincipalName

New-AdUser -UserPrincipalName "$accountname" -path "OU=Services,OU=Users,OU=OrgA,DC=testdomain,DC=local" -Name "$accountname" -SamAccountName "$accountname" -GivenName "$accountname" -Description $des -CannotChangePassword $true -DisplayName "$accountname" -PasswordNeverExpires $true -AccountPassword $spw -Enabled $true -otherAttributes $otherAttributes